# Render collada [.dae] file in iOS

Tags: ios, collada, 3d-rendering

I need to render 3D model which is of type **.dae [collada]** in iOS,

I have searched and found couple of links

- [Wavefront](https://code.google.com/p/iphonewavefrontloader/)
- [Molecules](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/molecules)
- [openscenegraph](http://www.openscenegraph.com)
- [iSGL3D](https://github.com/isgl3d/isgl3d)

but I am not sure whether they will support .dae files.

Is there any framework which [Collada](https://collada.org/) is giving for iOS developer?
so that it can be very reliable.

Could anyone please help me with this.

**Please note :** I am new to 3D rendering,can we render .dae files directly in iOS or do we need to convert to any other format ?

As I was searching in S.O I got  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304316/render-collada-dae-file-on-ios) link but that question is not answered.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check out this engine [NinevehGL](http://nineveh.gl) is in beta, but it has awesome capabilities and it supports a lot of formats.
Unfortunately Apple didn't released Scenekit for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

You can also render using Mitsuba 
http://www.mitsuba-renderer.org/download.html